# Set Default Font Style for Specific Tags in Portion of Page

Tags: html, css, css-specificity

What is the best, most maintainable and readable approach to setting a CSS property as the default for given tags in a portion of a page with low specificity. Currently, I have a page which takes the global default font styling from a `html` selector in a separate global stylesheet. There is a large portion of my page (which has the class `dash`) which I want to have a different default font style.

The main issue with just setting `.dash h1 { font.... }` is that this has very high specificity. Every time I want to set a font style for an element which is a descendant of `.dash`, I need to refer to `.dash`. Since I am working around a modular design, where each component is developed independently, this is a very bad idea. An even worse solution would be to set `!important` or to use an ID, for obvious reasons. Obviously, we don't run into this issue when setting fonts for `html h1`, or any other tag since all tags have lower specificity than classes.

Is there a simple low-specificity approach to setting a CSS property for tags which are descendants of an element high up in the DOM, selected by a class such that it can be overwritten by applying font properties to and element selected by another class?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Based on Harry Roberts article http://csswizardry.com/2014/07/hacks-for-dealing-with-specificity/#safely-increasing-specificity, I applied the same class repeatedly in order to increase the specificity of that selector above that applied to the portion (which itself is set simply as `.portion-class tag`).

See:

- Harry Roberts: http://jsfiddle.net/csswizardry/3N53n/3/ - note use of `.btn.btn` on line 28.
- mine: http://jsfiddle.net/Emsap/5/ - note use of `.dash-heading.dash-heading` on line 2

Note that I was, of course, wrong to think that the location of elements in the DOM was affecting the specificity.

Comment: This does not answer the question asked and does not contain any actual answer, just links.

Comment: I'm sorry if you feel that I haven't expressed myself well.

The "simple low-specificity approach to setting a CSS property for tags which are descendants of an element high up in the DOM, selected by a class", is simply provided as `.dash h4`.

Which "can be overwritten by applying font properties to and element selected by another class" by repeatedly re-apply that class `dash-heading`. Which I described in my answer as applying "the same class repeatedly in order to increase the specificity of that selector above that applied to the whole page."

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela do you have any suggestions as to how I can improve this answer to make it clearer?

Answer (score 1):

You can set font properties with a rule like `.dash { font ... }` and set font properties for elements inside the element so styled, because each element gets it font properties from the declarations that apply to it, rather than its parent or other ascendant.

For example, if you have

```
<div class=dash>
some content
<h2>some heading</h2>
some content
</div>
```

and you set

```
.dash { font-family: Cambria }
```

then there is no problem in setting

```
h2 { font-family: Calibri }
```

without referring to the `dash` class. The `h2` element gets its font family from the latter rule, quite independently of the rule that applies to its parent.

Comment: I apologise, I wasn't clear, please see http://jsfiddle.net/Emsap/3/ for an example of my issue.

Comment: @JoshBambrick, the question wasn’t crystal clear, but clear enough to be answered. What you say in the jsfiddle is completely different. It should be asked as a new question (with explanations of what you are really doing), if it is relevant. But I don’t think there will be interesting answers. It seems that what you want is to make a rule win without making it more (or even equally) specific and without using `!important`—basically, how to use CSS without adhering to basic CSS logic (the cascade).

Comment: What I want to do is to make the rule more specific without having to specify a class higher up the DOM and without limiting the tags which the rule may be used with - not avoiding making the rule more specific. It may well be the case that this is not possible.

Comment: See below for my solution, which avoids adding extra classes, or having to specify tag names or using `!important`.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't

```
.dash * { font
```

do what you need?

**UPDATE** after clarifying comments and fiddles ...

So, I had your question "backwards" because I thought you were trying to ignore specifics in the included html.

BUT I think my suggestion still works, no?

```
.dash * { color: red; }
.included-class { color: blue /* this will take precedence */ }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zDVED/

Comment: no, unfortunately that has similar issues to `.dash { ...`

Comment: I must not understand the question, because it works for me. http://jsfiddle.net/Emsap/

Comment: Ok, so I did have it backwards a bit, but I think the * is still the answer. See my updated answer and fiddle.

Comment: yes, but I want to select elements of a given tag name in `dash`, not all elements

Comment: Gotcha, so I'm guessing you want to avoid !important because you don't like the mess? or because you don't want composers on that end to have to do it?

Comment: because it is so over-specific that it would get messy.

Comment: I assume your pages are generated somehow. Would it make sense to parse this stuff out at that stage?